# UPDATE with SELECT leads to deadlock

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, deadlock

I have a very simple update statement within one job step:

```
UPDATE [Table]
SET 
[Flag] = 1
WHERE [ID] = (SELECT MAX([ID]) FROM [Table] WHERE [Name] = 'DEV')
```

Normally there are no issues with this code, but sometimes it ends up with the deadlock.

Is it in general possible, that such stand-alone piece of code leads to a deadlock?

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [Table]
(
  [ID]   [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [Name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [Flag] [bit] NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [Table_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)
```

Comment: Please add details of the table schema, indexes and the deadlock graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deadlock cause is quite obvious: there is no index on `Name`, so it's going to scan the whole table for the subquery. There is also no `UPDLOCK` hint on it, so that is also going to make deadlocks more likely.

Create an index on `Name`

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Name ON [Table] (Name) INCLUDE (ID);
```

And make sure you use `UPDLOCK` on the subquery

```sql
UPDATE [Table]
SET Flag = 1
WHERE ID = (
    SELECT MAX(ID)
    FROM [Table] t2 WITH (UPDLOCK)
    WHERE t2.Name = 'DEV')
```

---

This query is much more efficiently written without a self-join, like this:

```sql
UPDATE t
SET Flag = 1
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (1)
      *
    FROM [Table] t
    WHERE t.Name = 'DEV'
    ORDER BY ID DESC
) t;
```

Even though the optimizer can often transform into this version, it's better to just write it like this anyway.

This version does not need a `UPDLOCK`, it will be added automatically. You still need the above index though.

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=560f1c0837dd61160cefea1feb83a50f)

Comment: Thanks! Just for my understanding: why do I need an UPDATE hint, if there will be an index to separate read and update operations?

Comment: Because in your version, the table reference that is being read from is not the one that is being updated, so you need tomake sure the lock is held and not released. It will normally be released under `READ COMMITTED` isolation

Comment: @Charlieface "This version does not need a UPDLOCK, it will be added automatically" could you elaborate on this little gem please?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2812532/14868997 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver16#update. U-locks are only taken on a table reference that is the direct target of the `UPDATE` or `DELETE`, so here only the outer reference to `Table` has a U-lock. You need to force an earlier U-lock using `UPDLOCK`. In the new version of the query, there is only one table reference which is directly updated, this will get a U-lock automatically.

Comment: @Charlieface : But why do we need an index in case we're going to use your version? The table will be scanned once, the row will be selected, then the UPDLOCK will be automatically set on that row and after that the update will convert the lock to (X) and the row will be updated. What is the advantage of using a new index? (besides speeding up the performance)

Comment: True if this was the only query being run, but if there is another query scanning in a different order (different index) you are less likely to deadlock during the scan phase if you can do a point lookup. The obvious performance increase is also worthwhile.